# Only one branch is retrieved when shallow clone is made in GIT

Tags: git

I'm trying to shrink a big repository to reduce server load. I'm using the command

```
git clone --depth 1000 url
```

But when the clone is finished I only have one branch. The branches not cloned are new (3 weeks or so) and the history cloned has 3 months, so those branches has to be inside that history. If I try to search all branches with

```
git branch -a
```

only one branch is shown.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shallow clones default to only getting a single branch. If you want to get all branches, pass `--no-single-branch` to `git clone`.

Comment: Why that's true, until recently the docs where not really clear on this. But it has been [clarified](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28a1b56932c222b326e4ac0cd480d4e0be72fb1c) for Git 2.7.1.

Comment: Yes, you found the solution! Thanks!