# How to clone a big git repository using slow/unstable network connection?

Tags: git

I've seen some similar questions here, but they're not really explain how to clone a big git repository when you deal with slow/unstable network connection.

Basically what I did so far was the following:

```
$ git clone --depth=1 https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux.git/
Cloning into 'linux'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1089, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1089/1089), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (738/738), done.
remote: Total 1089 (delta 48), reused 651 (delta 31)
Receiving objects: 100% (1089/1089), 1.49 MiB | 66.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (48/48), done.
```

That command created a `shallow` local repository with only the last commit:

```
$ git log --all --oneline

7d94791 (grafted, HEAD -> refs/heads/master, refs/remotes/origin/master, refs/remotes/origin/HEAD) Update to 4.20.7
```

Now I should use one of the following commands (or some mix of them):

```
$ git fetch --deepen=100
$ git fetch --depth=100
```

The first one will fetch additional 100 commits and hence the local repository will have now 101 commits. The second one will fetch 99 commits the local repo will have 100 commits in total.

I was playing with the values till ultimately I got this:

```
$ git fetch --depth=10000
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

$ git fetch --unshallow
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense
```

It says that I have a complete repository, but that's not true. Reading the git stats (online), I can see it has **13,746 Commits** , 29 Branches , 1,418 , Tags , **2.2 GB** Files. According to the info in the similar questions, if that was the full clone, it should have `--depth=13746` , but it doesn't event have `10000` .

The problem here is in `29 Branches` , and I only cloned the `master` one.

The question here is actually: how to clone the rest of the branches in similar way so I get the whole repository?

I noticed that in the `.git/config` file I have the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux.git/
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

When I change the third line to:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

It will fetch the rest of the branches.

I also tried to use the following instead:

```
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
    fetch = +refs/heads/sid:refs/remotes/origin/sid
```

Which fetched only the `sid` branch:

```
$ git remote update && git status                                                                         
Fetching origin                                                                                                                            
remote: Enumerating objects: 209, done.                                                                                                    
remote: Counting objects: 100% (209/209), done.                                                                                            
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (72/72), done.                                                                                           
remote: Total 209 (delta 92), reused 199 (delta 89)                                                                                        
Receiving objects: 100% (209/209), 260.34 KiB | 136.00 KiB/s, done.                                                                        
Resolving deltas: 100% (92/92), done.                                                                                                      
From https://salsa.debian.org/kernel-team/linux                                                                                            
 * [new branch]          sid        -> origin/sid                                                          
On branch master                                                                                                 
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.                                                                                           

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Now I have

```
$ git branch -a

* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/sid
```

I think something is missing here, but I don't really know what and whether simply adding another `fetch = +refs...` lines is the right way to go.

I can get the list of branches in the following way:

```
$ git ls-remote --heads origin
af210b506d24cf7585629e346c921aed90e07133        refs/heads/carnil/import-4.14.14
a56ffb69de38383f26e77b740b9270ee0faf834c        refs/heads/carnil/jessie-security/CVE-2017-7533
7c1804aa712bae44319bd481523c0500df16733b        refs/heads/carnil/stretch-security/CVE-2017-7533
0205ec9ec76ff2d993241a55628e3bd196ecec44        refs/heads/dgit-master
0839599a02f9cbbcb1933e4a60bcbbcf5bcacc11        refs/heads/etch
46f3979bd0f6a567b563f0c99f95c592067e94bb        refs/heads/etch-security
a0fe8cfa8617c895bf6d42383e1975199f342c5b        refs/heads/etchnhalf
66235807ed13884dc8986d9238f83c54baa26ace        refs/heads/etchnhalf-security
7b995d73957608b43a4b2dfacfa9e17bdc37e711        refs/heads/jessie
1d63dcd6296b9ad495d1a7d70c63fa5db68b77b7        refs/heads/jessie-backports
5009a129295a70d8017974c9821ecdd12d7d9675        refs/heads/jessie-security
c7b190d1b45dd7a7df71eb0651b677754972f7fd        refs/heads/jessie-security-4.9
13bc212fa183d61162a1708df0ee9382c0ac66f0        refs/heads/jessie-updates
cd2e2790cfeebeec461ce28530f23b8bf0e24e7b        refs/heads/lenny
14865a3daf8e808072ebca063297815e0967b129        refs/heads/lenny-security
7d94791b95d147a13f2eae4fa9a5e852c95330c9        refs/heads/master
ce61976b4810abb7e88f0bf08dc8efc7e6a19dc5        refs/heads/rosh/armel_mini
26e9f62e399a67e454ff40deca2eef531c279139        refs/heads/sid
9e549e30eb6e12e97f3ff29497821aa41564ee93        refs/heads/squeeze
f8d465883cbbf23432db1d0139f0b43e570ebc9d        refs/heads/squeeze-backports
03cf6ed02e5128674ac954b345cdea2a3c6b9ddd        refs/heads/squeeze-security
155c325ba50c3cdd60d9fcdfdd961a4a636a6367        refs/heads/stretch
5357a00fc4892878f8e532862540a575df621e2c        refs/heads/stretch-backports
0a50b0efbc995f6c5710f4d52e321ef6102ee298        refs/heads/stretch-security
1d69dac66c315a290fb61c5f400e056e8d01fe50        refs/heads/ukleinek/jessie
beed93421656d6290a4fe3952e6a29696a6cbaf7        refs/heads/waldi/cloud-arm64
15ca73ce51f27d275a1e67e570cfe3a13ade3368        refs/heads/wheezy
b479e71dc9fd2215f08b3ea795e0fe9264cc39c3        refs/heads/wheezy-backports
6a47ea238773fa11bb694bd2a0fedc1549dff118        refs/heads/wheezy-security
```

How to add and fetch (in some automated way) each of the branch?

Comment: Your diagnosis was correct, as was your change. You can use `--no-single-branch` during the initial clone if you like. I'll close this as a duplicate though yours is actually the much better question. :-)

Comment: With a good beer in your sofa!?!

Comment: @torek: Could you please change the duplicate link to point directly to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504339/only-one-branch-is-retrieved-when-shallow-clone-is-made-in-git? The current duplicate has been deleted.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: fixed. StackOverflow forced me to remove the deleted one, which is interesting since it's actually still there in the database. Not sure why they don't just auto-add any additional duplicates.

Comment: i faced the same issue with a bad internet connection. So i came up with the following solution:
Created a small php file on my server to download the package as a zip file:

    <?php
    $url = "https://codeload.github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/zip/master";
    file_put_contents("coco.zip", fopen($url, 'r'));
    ?>  
    
    <a href="coco.zip">coco.zip</a>

then download the zip file using any download manager that supports resume

Comment: working solution :

you need to turn off the compression:

    git config --global core.compression 0

then you need to use shallow clone

    git clone --depth=1 <url>

then most important step is to cd into your cloned project

    cd <shallow cloned project dir>

now deopen the clone,step by step

    git fetch --depth=N, with increasing N

eg.

    git fetch --depth=4

then,

    git fetch --depth=100

then,

    git fetch --depth=500

 you can choose how many steps you want by replacing this N,
and finally.

    git fetch --unshallow